# Using tables inside Accordion

Tags: jquery

How can we use HTML table inside Accordion??

I have a code:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>DIV 1 CONTENTS</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>A2</th>
                <th>B2</th>
                <th>C2</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>A3</th>
                <th>B3</th>
                <th>C3</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>A4</th>
                <th>B4</th>
                <th>C4</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code (using 1.9.1):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

But the output of this stops when it encounters table and  the accordion does not work...

Any solution for this??

Comment: I can't help thinking this is likely to be because you're missing a close tag/quote somewhere. Are you 100% sure your html is valid?

Comment: Hi Liath, Without accordion, it works perfectly.. but with accordion it doesnot..

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/c0uxs681/. Works as expected.